# Pandas update() runs very long

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 [4182 rows x 164952 columns]
df2 [1810 rows x 8457 columns]
```

when i try `df1.update(df2, overwrite=True)` my script runs very long.
How to speed up the code?

Comment: Hi @hyper, What are you trying to achieve? Can you post small sample dataframes in code text and show your expected result?

Comment: you should reduce the number of columns in `df1` to those which might be updated in the process. Currently, you are checking > 150000 columns in `df1` for vain

Comment: As @E.Sommer already pointed out, a simple `df1[[col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns]].update(df2, overwrite = True)` should already significantly improve performance ~20 fold

Comment: what if I do this `df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns].update(df2, overwrite=True)` ?

Comment: How to reduce the time of the code, if we accept that df1 consists of zeros?

Comment: @hyper, you're not going to get much help without posing code, runtimes, or anything that people can work off of. If your df1 is all 0's then it sounds like you should rethink your entire process. An entire df is a waste of memory/time for this task. Look into representing your data with a scipy [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for instance

Comment: Thank you all, I did it: `df2=df2.reindex(index=df2.index.union(df1.index))
 df2=df2.reindex(columns=df2.columns.union(df1.columns))
 df2=df2.fillna(0)`